# How to map values from a dataframe and get the last update

Tags: pandas, dictionary, mapping

I'm stuck with a problem because map() don't let me map values if they are repeated. The scenario is this.

I have this df1 of daily observations

```
   Obvserved_Today  A   B  
0  192.168.1.1      3   2
1  192.168.1.3      1   3
2  192.168.1.4      1   5
3  192.168.1.5      2   9
```

I want to update that df by adding two columns of historical data, so I already have this second dataframe df2 of historics

```
   IP_Historical    Ticket  Date  
0  192.168.1.1      3001    11/01/2020
1  192.168.1.1      3002    11/02/2020
2  192.168.1.3      3003    11/03/2020
3  192.168.1.5      3004    11/04/2020
4  192.168.1.5      3005    11/05/2020
```

I want an output like the one below, I want to add two more columns, the first one containing the last ticket seen in the historical df2 and a second one, also from the historical df2, with the last seen date if there's no match let it as NaN or 0.

```
   Obvserved_Today  A   B   Last Ticket  Last update
0  192.168.1.1      3   2   3002         11/02/2020
1  192.168.1.3      1   3   3003         11/03/2020
2  192.168.1.4      1   5   0            0
3  192.168.1.5      2   9   3005         11/05/2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1.merge(df2[~df2.duplicated('Obvserved_Today',keep='last')], how='left', on='Obvserved_Today')
```

This will have the columns named "Ticket" instead of "Last Ticket" and "Date" instead of "Last update". If you want you can rename after the merge.

**What is this code doing?**

It is merging the two dataframe (looking at the `on=` column and matching up same values) but only looking at the rows of the second dataframe that are the last of the observation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @noah, it worked pefectly.